# Equivalence of trigonometric identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Is writing $$
  \cot{2\theta}=\frac{a-c}{2b}
$$ equivalent to $$
  \cot{\theta}=\frac{a}{b},\tan{\theta}=\frac{c}{b}
$$

becuase of the trigonometric identity $$
  \cot{2\theta}=\frac{\cot{\theta}-\tan{\theta}}{2}
$$

Comment: No.  Let $a-c=2$, then $a$ could equal $4$ and $c=2$ or $a$ could equal $87.5$ and $c=85.5$.  So which $a$ corresponds to the correct one for $\cot(\theta)$, who knows?  Without further info, the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Choose e.g. $b=1$ and $a = c$. Then $\cot(2\theta) = 0$, so $\theta  = \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{k\pi}{2}$. This implies that $\cot(\theta) = \pm 1$. Choosing any $a$ different from $\pm 1$ gives you a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

> Simply, No

Rememeber $$\tan\theta=\frac{1}{\cot\theta}$$

Now let $x=\tan\theta$
and we have $$\frac{a-c}{b}=\frac{1}{x}-x$$

$$x^2+\left(\frac{a-c}{b}\right)x-1=0$$

Now you can solve this quadratic an obtain expression for $\tan\theta$ and $\cot\theta$